# How to Revert database to last modified from recent Restore?

Tags: sql-server

me and my fried were developing a project in separate system but created database in same name, Today i restored my database in my friend's machine accidentally.
Is there any way to roll back the database in SQL-Server, which means i want to get database that i  restore before.

Comment: Do you have a backup? Yes: restore it. No: you can do nothing

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

This is actually a very good event, take this as an opportunity to stop modifying and copying the database *files*. As developers your deliverable is source code, including the source code code for database **scripts** to deploy and upgrade the database. Have a look at [Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) for an elegant approach. Use [Visual Studio Database Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678491%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Or [roll your own](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/). Just never, ever, touch the database from the object explorer.

BTW, The RESTORE command blocks restoring a database from overwriting a different database. You must had explicitly overwritten the blocking.